# setState for an array of objects in handleChange is not working

Tags: arrays, reactjs, elasticsearch, search, state

I au using elasticsearch to do searching in my view (ReactJs). I created a function handleChange to change the state of the data in the table according to what I am searching.
so I did this so far in my code :

```
var esClient = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: 'localhost:9200',
  log: 'info'
});

class MesExtraits extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      MP3info: [],
      searchText: '',
    }
  }

  updateSearch = (evt) => {
    this.setState({ searchText: evt.target.value, });
    var searchQ = evt.target.value;
    var search_queryES = "titre:" + searchQ + "*"

    esClient.search({
      q: search_queryES
    }).then(function (body) {
      this.setState({ MP3info: body.hits.hits.map(i => i._source) })

      console.log(this.state.MP3info)

      console.log(body.hits.hits.map(i => i._source))

    }.bind(this), function (error) {
      console.trace(error.message);
    });
  };

  render() {

    const { MP3info } = this.state;
    return (

      <div>
        <SearchBox styleName="gx-d-none gx-d-lg-block gx-lt-icon-search-bar-lg"
          placeholder="Search in app..."
          onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)}
          value={this.state.searchText}
        />
        <Paper className={classes.root}>
          <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell><IntlMessages id="MP3.titre" /></TableCell>
                <TableCell align="left"><IntlMessages id="MP3.descfiption" /></TableCell>
                <TableCell align="left"><IntlMessages id="MP3.langue" /></TableCell>
                <TableCell align="left"><IntlMessages id="MP3.stats" /></TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {MP3info.map(row => (
                <TableRow key={row.titre}>
                  <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                    {row.titre}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="left">{row.description}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="left">{row.langue}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="left"> <span id={row.idMedia} onClick={this.onClickPoup}><i class="icon icon-chart" /> </span> </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </Paper>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is when I `console.log(this.state.MP3info)` after setState for MP3info it is not changing.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous.
so it will work like this:

```
this.setState({ MP3info: body.hits.hits.map(i => i._source) }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.MP3info)
})
```

from documentation:

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
>   componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater,
>   callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
>   has been applied.

Answer (score 2):

After calling setState, you cannot expect the state to be updated immediately since setState is an asynchronous operation.

However, there is an optional 2nd parameter of a callback function which you can use in setState, if you want to do something immediately after updating the state.

```
this.setState({
        value: newStateValue,
    }, () => {
     const { value } = this.state; // access the updated value here
    })
```

Please follow this beautiful explanation of how setState works! [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/get-pro-with-react-setstate-in-10-minutes-d38251d1c781/)

Also:

#### When not to use the callback:

React docs recommend that you use the lifecycle events.

Here’s why.

`PureComponent` and `shouldComponentUpdate` can be used to tune up a component’s performance. They work by preventing lifecycle methods from firing when props and state haven’t changed.

> The `setState` callback fires regardless of what `shouldComponentUpdate` returns. So, the `setState` callback will fire, even when state hasn’t changed.

So.. Don’t be afraid to use the setState callback. It’s there for a reason. But when you do, keep an eye on shouldComponentUpdate, if you see any shiftiness.